# How to connect pod to hbase in sparkoperator k8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, hbase

I want to run file spark get data from hbase and print them.
When I run file spark.py in local, it's ok. But i run in K8s it error.

This is my file yaml

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: hbase-v1
  namespace: spark-jobs
spec:
  type: Python
  pythonVersion: "3"
  mode: cluster
  image: "yami1012/hbase-spark:latest"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: local:///opt/spark/code_hbase/spark.py
  sparkVersion: "3.3.2"
  restartPolicy:
    type: OnFailure
    onFailureRetries: 3 
    onFailureRetryInterval: 10
    onSubmissionFailureRetries: 5
    onSubmissionFailureRetryInterval: 20
  sparkConf:
    spark.driver.host: "localhost"
  driver:
    hostNetwork: true
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "1200m"
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.1
    serviceAccount: spark
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 1
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.1
```

When i apply file yaml, driver is error.
It's error is:

```
Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I run this image with network=host and i submit file spark.py, it's ok

I tried create service headless, it's not run

Please help me!